# SQL DATE TIME FORMAT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two `DATE` columns that contain random dates. I want to convert their format to `dd.mm.yyyy` and I think its code is 104.

I made some research on internet but they all use getdate function for sql but i don't want to convert today's date. I want to convert all dates in Column that names are A and B. How can i do that?

Thanx

Comment: Show table structure, example of data and result example. Because this is unclear question.

Comment: Like @slavoo said, we need more information to properly answer your question. Please indicate which SQL provider you're using (Oracle, SQL Server...). Are the columns data types `DATE` or `DATETIME` or something else? If the are a `DATE` or `DATETIME`, your question is likely a formatting question rather than how the data is stored. So in that case, what tool are you using or thinking of using to present the data?

Comment: use convert like here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp Just remember to change GETDATE to your column name, something like select CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), YOUR_COLUMN,104) as yourFormattedDate FROM YOURTABLENAME

Comment: First of all i'm using MSSQL server 2008r2. Their data types are Date but if it's necessary i can change them to DATETIME. I need to convert them to dd.mm.yyyy format because i will import these dates to c#

Comment: @MarceloBezerra thanx it worked for a column. of course i can write a code too for other column but is there any way for convert them together with just a code?

Comment: @user3218867 In this case (inport to `c#`) format it in application, not in database layer.

Comment: what do you mean by "convert them together with just a code"? you want to concatenate two formatted dates and return then concatenated as a single column? you can use concat: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/hh231515.aspx

Comment: SQL Server `DATE` columns do ***not*** have any *format* associated with them - they are 3 byte binary data. The format only comes into play when you want to *display* the date - in SQL Server Management Studio, or your own application. Therefore, you *cannot* "set a format" - it's just not possible, since there is none.....

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
SELECT 
   CONVERT(char(10), column1, 104) AS column1_conv, 
   CONVERT(char(10), column2, 104) AS column2_conv...
```

Comment: 'my date'? there are lots of different dates in columns.

Comment: use this for each column where you have to... or are there multiple dates within a single column?